# How to calculate the maximum current that a wire can handle?

Tags: current, current-measurement, current-limiting

What are the methods that manufactures used to do so ?
What is the formula used if there is a one to do so?

Comment: Not simply AWG .  It depends on thermal resistance of insulation for T=85'C or higher  But current doubles every 3 gauge numbers e.g. AWG16 to 13

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Not quite.  If you double cross section and double current, the wire makes 2x as much heat. But it only has 1.414x the circumference to dissipate that heat through.  This sort of factor is why the NEC thermal ratings in 310.15 are complicated. OP, also look in the UL White Book.